# IMEX=1 seems to have no effect

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string, oledb, adodb

I use ADODB to pull data from Excel file to another Excel file without opening the source. I have a strong suspicion that the `IMEX=1` parameter is not accepted in my connection. I start my connection like this:

```
con1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
 "Data Source=" & sFile & ";" & _
 "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;"""
```

So I explicitly state that I want `IMEX=1` to be used, but I find it not working, although it exists in the connection properties tree:
[image: connection properties - IMEX]

**The Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**

**1.** Create a file `C:/Temp/Source.xlsx` where you should enter these 9 values:
[image: Source]
Save and close this file.

**2.** Paste the following code in any other (new) worksheet which should have a sheet named "Sheet1" and run it:

```
Sub PullData()

    Dim con1 As Object
    Dim rst1 As Object
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim x As Long, Y As Long, Xupper As Long, Yupper As Long
    Dim arrData() As Variant, arrTransp() As Variant
    Dim rngTargStart As Range

    Set con1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sFile = "C:\Temp\Source.xlsx"

    con1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
     "Data Source=" & sFile & ";" & _
     "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;"""

    'pulling
    rst1.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A9];", con1, 3, 1
    x = rst1.RecordCount '.GetRows sometimes yields "Record is too large". This line fixes it.
    arrData = rst1.GetRows
    rst1.Close

    'transposing
    Xupper = UBound(arrData, 2)
    Yupper = UBound(arrData, 1)
    ReDim arrTransp(Xupper, Yupper)
    For x = 0 To Xupper
        For Y = 0 To Yupper
            arrTransp(x, Y) = arrData(Y, x)
        Next
    Next

    'updating worksheet
    Set rngTargStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    rngTargStart.Resize(UBound(arrTransp, 1) + 1, UBound(arrTransp, 2) + 1).Value = arrTransp

    con1.Close
    Set con1 = Nothing
    Set rst1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

After running it I get this:
[image: outcome]

**Any idea why, and how to fix it?** I'll greatly appreciate any comments.

The full `con1.connectionstring` looks like this:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Temp\Source.xlsx;Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False;

I use Office Pro Plus 2013, 32-bit on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

So originally I thought that `IMEX=1` prevents any evaluation of any number of values and just imports every value as text. Apparently one cannot prevent from evaluating values (by default 8 values are evaluated). What `IMEX=1` actually does, is storing every value in a column as text ONLY if certain criteria are met on those 8 evaluated cells. I tested different sets of source data to understand how those 8 values are evaluated (which values take precedence over other in deciding if all values in a column will be treated as text, and therefore, imported). This is the result.

***Text values*** > Numeric values > **Text format** > (Custom format) > Numeric format > **formatted cells** > General format empty cells

The values in bold lets the whole column be imported (treated as text), only if there are no values of higher precedence within those 8 evaluated cells. E.g., if within the first 8 cells there are 7 empty cells which are formatted as text and one cell which has an actual number inside, you will not have your text data imported (blank values will be imported instead).

*Detailed results of testing:*

If you have any actual text value within the first 8 cells, you will always succeed to import all the values in a column:
[image]
If there is any number value and no text values within the first 8 cells, you will fail to import text values in that column (blank values will be imported instead):
[image]
[image]
Now, if you have no values within your first 8 cells, and at least one of them is formatted as text, you will have your text values imported:
[image]
[image]
If all the 8 first cells are empty and if there is at least one number-formatted cell (no text-formatted cells), you will fail to import text values in that column (blank values will be imported instead):
[image]
[image]
<sub>However, the latter (only one numeric format) ***would successfully import text values*** in the column ***if the source workbook was not open*** in any instance of Excel at the time of import.</sub>

Then we have empty formatted cells (e.g. color format) - text values in the column would be successfully imported:
[image]
Another case - empty unformatted cells, but with some **data or formats *in another column***:
[image]
Finally, if there were no data or formats in other columns (perfectly cleared rows), your first rows might disappear from the output:
[image]

I skipped custom formats, as I think the outcome might depend on the actual format. My results were interesting, as when the source book was open, I successfully imported text data in the column, but when it was closed, I didn't. My guess is that custom formats, when the workbook is closed, might be treated as number formats.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is really weird - I noticed that I'm getting blank columns ONLY during a join when the table I'm joining has blank cells for the first 10 cells in a particular column. Changing the formats doesn't seem to bring the data over regardless of what I do - the only thing that brings the column over is to populate some of those top cells with data. What a weird, frustrating bug. It works just fine if I do `SELECT * FROM TableName` - they all come over regardless. If, however, I join a table to another one, those 3 columns that are blank for the first 11 rows or so are entirely blank after join.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://www.etl-tools.com/imex1.html) explains it pretty well. Basically, it works out that the input column is numeric. When it gets to row 9 and finds text, it could crash and usually would. Since IMEX is set to 1, it doesn't crash, and instead returns a null for the value. If you had a 10th row with 8 in it, that would get imported as 8 into row 10.

However if IMEX is not set, then an error will be generated, so it's working as expected as far as I can see.